# React router: Redirecting with url param?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my render function I have

```
<Route path="/classes/:course" render={(match) => (
   <Redirect to={`/classes/${match.params.course}/home`} />
)}>
   <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
</Route>
```

For example if the param for "course" was "BIO1001", I want to redirect the page to "/classes/BIO1001/home" when I go to the page "/classes/BIO1001/". Previously I tried simply putting a Redirect tag with "from" and "to" but ran into the problem of the url actually going to "/classes/:course/home" instead of "/classes/BIO1001/home"

Also would the nested route with path="/home" go to "/classes/BIO1001/home"? I was unsure on how I can set a route where the path starts from the previous url (in this case starting from "/classes/:course/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is right here:

```
render={(match) => ( ...
```

The `render` function gets a props object which contains a `match` property.  Instead of destructuring the `match` property, what you are actually doing is assigning the whole `props` object to a variable `match`.  So when you go to access `match.params` it won't be found.

You need curly braces around `match` in order to destructure it.

```
render={({match}) => ( ...
```

The second problem is the nesting of the two `Route` components.  I get a warning:

> Warning: You should not use `<Route render>` and `<Route children>` in the same route; `<Route render>` will be ignored

So based on that warning you can see that your `Redirect` is being entirely ignored since it comes from `render`.  The child `Route` is seen as the render function for the classes `Route`.

I'm assuming you have various subpages of a course?  And we want to force the URL to include "/home" if none is set? (Personally I would do the opposite and redirect "/home" to the course root URL).

> Previously I tried simply putting a Redirect tag with "from" and "to" but ran into the problem of the url actually going to "/classes/:course/home" instead of "/classes/BIO1001/home"

Per [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect), you can use params in your `Redirect`, but only if it is inside a `Switch`.

Here's a sample code to do that:

```
const CoursePage = () => {
  // you can access arguments from the props or through hooks
  const { course, tab } = useParams();

  // not sure how you want to handle the different tabs

  return <div>Viewing Course {course}</div>;
};

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/classes/:course/:tab"><CoursePage/></Route>
      <Redirect from="/classes/:course" to="/classes/:course/home"/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: This code still goes to the url with the params ":course" instead of the actual course params. i.e. If I enter localhost:3000/classes/BIO1001, it redirects to localhost:3000/classes/:course/home.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to others, but the Redirect component with from and to will actually only work as a child of Switch. That means even a fractional component (<></>) will cause params to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested routing is true i think. But you are rendering your Home component without any dynamic props. Try it like below:

```
<Route path="/classes/:course" render={(match) => (
   <Redirect to={`/classes/${match.params.course}/home`} />
)}>
   <Route path="/home" >
      <Home someProps={someValue} />
   </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: add sample code in codesandbox for testing

Answer (score 0):

Note: The `Redirect` element can be used without a containing `Route` element by providing a `from` property.  In this case, you can just use the URL parameter tokens in both `from` and `to`, and they'll be carried over for you.  For example, if you're using a `Switch` block...

```
<Switch>
  {/* various app routes... */}

  {/* redirect action */}
  <Redirect from="/classes/:course" to="/classes/:course/home" />
<Switch>
```